# How to write and read bytes from unsigned variable

Tags: c++, unsigned, short, binaries

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have two integers

```
int a = 0; // can be 0 or 1
int b = 3; // can be 0, 1, 2 or 3
```

Also I want to have

```
unsigned short c
```

to store that variables inside it.

For example, if I would store **a** inside **c** it will be looking like this:

```
00000000
^ here is a
```

Then I need to store b inside c. And it should look like following:

```
011000000
 ^^ here is b.
```

Also I would like to read that numbers back after writing them.
How can I do this?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming those are binary representations of the numbers and assuming that you really meant to have five zeros to the right of b

```
01100000
 ^^ here is b
```

(the way you have it a and b overlap)

Then this is how to do it

```
// write a to c
c &= ~(1 << 7);
c |= a << 7;

// write b to c
c &= ~(3 << 5);
c |= b << 5;

// read a from c
a = (c >> 7)&1;

// read b from c
b = (c >> 5)&3;
```

Comment: @john @brian-gradin One more question. What if I try to add another variable, same as b, for axample, and would like to store it in c. How could I do that? `int d = 3; c &= ~(5 << 2); c |= d << 2; d = (c >> 2)&5;` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Store with `c &= ~(3 << 3); c |= d << 3;`.  Pull with `d = (c >> 3) & 3;`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [C++ Bit Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=vs.120%29.aspx):

```
struct MyBitfield
{
    unsigned short a : 1;
    unsigned short b : 2;
};
MyBitfield c;
c.a = // 0 or 1
c.b = // 0 or 1 or 2 or 3
```